# Debug Docker DNS

Tags: docker, dns, networking, virtualization

In a stack with higher number of services it seems that Docker DNS does not work anymore which leads to effects that container's names are not known even to themselves.

While I have filed [this bug](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/988), I wonder whether there is a way to debug this more extensively to "prove" the DNS error, or for example manually "fix" the DNS name.

Will be there some deeper error message?

**Note**: The ping from outside does not work; I just find cumbersome that is not possible to ping your own DNS name.

Comment: Did you login to several containers and check whether ping other-dockername works? When I check the docker-compose, I read `cassandra-seed`. So ping cassandra-seed from one of the docker containers should work. Does it?

Comment: The ping from outside does not work; I just find cumbersome that is not possible to ping your own DNS name.

Comment: What do you mean with `outside`, e.g. outside the POD, the k8s cluster?

Comment: It’s not too difficult to open an interactive bash shell inside a docket instance. Could ping via that and verify what the system’s actual state is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505506/ddg#507009

Answer (score 2):

There is a comprehensive [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#troubleshooting-tips) about k8s' DNS. According to this document one could validate whether the DNS is working by running:

busybox.yaml

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: busybox
>   namespace: default
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - image: busybox
>     command:
>       - sleep
>       - "3600"
>     imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
>     name: busybox
>   restartPolicy: Always
> ```

and deploy it by issuing:

> ```
> kubectl create -f busybox.yaml
> ```

Once deployed, one could run:

> ```
> kubectl get pods busybox
> ```

and validate whether the DNS is working:

> ```
> kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
> ```

There are additional validation steps that could be executed, including:

> ```
> kubectl exec busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
> ```

verify the DNS policy, check whether the DNS pod runs, checking erros in the DNS pod:

> ```
> kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns
> kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c dnsmasq
> kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c sidecar
> ```

does the DNS service run?

> ```
> kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
> ```

exposed DNS endpoints?

> ```
> kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
> ```

There are also multiple known issues regarding the k8s' DNS:

> Linux’s libc is impossibly stuck (see this bug from 2005) with limits
>   of just 3 DNS nameserver records and 6 DNS search records. Kubernetes
>   needs to consume 1 nameserver record and 3 search records. This means
>   that if a local installation already uses 3 nameservers or uses more
>   than 3 searches, some of those settings will be lost. As a partial
>   workaround, the node can run dnsmasq which will provide more
>   nameserver entries, but not more search entries. You can also use
>   kubelet’s --resolv-conf flag.